# How to use other system icons?

Tags: ios, swift, icons, uibarbuttonitem, human-interface

Lately I wanted to include the iOS "star" icon in my NavigationBar. But when I looked at the `UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem` I noticed that these are limited to 21 icons/images. The "star" and many other icons used in many iOS apps (and even the official Guideline Keynote) are not included.

Is there a way to access them via code?

Comment: You will need to source your own artwork

Comment: You will need to create you own icon and set it as the `UIBarButton` in navigation bar. There is no way you can access other icons than already provided by Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use it as assets,
There are many icon websites that provide free and paid assets like [icons8](https://icons8.com/ios-icons/).

on another side, if you need those from Xcode there is an only way to make it, use this as UITabBarItem.

Those are the ones coming from the `UITabBarItem` init with `TabBarSystemItem`

**Simple example**

```
let favoritesItem = UITabBarItem.SystemItem.favorites
let bar = UITabBar(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 100, height: 60))
let barItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: favoritesItem, tag: 0)
bar.items = [barItem]
view.addSubview(bar)
```

See more may you need it [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/system-icons/)

You can also extract iOS SDK icons from SDK from [here](http://www.alexcurylo.com/2009/01/03/extracting-sdk-icons/) but I prefer to download it.

Comment: And how do I use the Tabbar item `let star = UITabBarItem.SystemItem.favorites` as my `rightBarButtonItem` ?

Comment: I update  the answer with a simple example with tab bar you can use it in navigation Bar and Toolbar Icons also